# servlet-class path in web.xml

Tags: java, xml, rest, servlets, jersey

I am following http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html tutorial.

I have created the project(Dyanamic web project) by name "JerseyDemoProject",created a package by name "Package1" and i have written the program Hello.java(which is given in the tutorial) in this package.

I have modified my web.xml as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JerseyDemoProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Package1.Hello</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>Package1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

When i try to "Run on server" ,It gives me 404- not found error.
I am using Tomcat server

Hello class:

```
package Package1;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// Plain old Java Object it does not extend as class or implements 
// an interface

// The class registers its methods for the HTTP GET request using the @GET annotation. 
// Using the @Produces annotation, it defines that it can deliver several MIME types,
// text, XML and HTML. 

// The browser requests per default the HTML MIME type.

//Sets the path to base URL + /hello
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

[image: Here is my project structure]

UPDATE:

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JerseyDemoProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>Package1</param-value>
      </init-param>

</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

class file

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

  // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {
    return "Hello Jersey";
  }

  // This method is called if XML is request
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
  public String sayXMLHello() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
  }

  // This method is called if HTML is request
  @GET
  @Path("/inhtmlform")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }

}
```

URL used

```
http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemoProject/rest/hello/inhtmlform
```

Error shown

```
HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Rootcause:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I found tese warnings in my console

```
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Informatica\961_989\961_Install\java\jre\bin\server;C:\Informatica\961_989\961_Install\tools\odbcdrv;C:\Informatica\961_989\961_Install\tools\jdbcdrv;C:\Informatica\961_989\961_Install\tools\datadirect;C:\app\vpalagum\product\11.2.0\client_2\bin;C:\app\vpalagum\product\11.2.0\client_1;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Box\Box Edit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk7_u15\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Softwares\eclipse4.2;;.

WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JerseyDemoProject' did not find a matching property.
```

Comment: for what URL are you getting 404? Paste the URL that is generated on browser when you run this on server

Comment: I am running it from eclipse.Right click "Hello.java" -> Run on server

Comment: URL shown is http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemoProject/WEB-INF/classes/Package1/Hello.java

Comment: You need to right click on your project and run that on server not your java file? Run that and see if issue still persists, paste the URL here

Comment: Ive tried that too.URL is http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemoProject/

Comment: and there is no JerseyDemoProject in my tomcat/webapps folder

Comment: Also please edit the question and paste Hello.java file content

Comment: What is that and where do i find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was because i am using jersey 2.1 .I removed it,installed Jersey 1.18 JARbundle from https://jersey.java.net/download.html . I added this jar in my WEB-INF lib folder , and also added asm.jar in this folder. (This jar can be found in Jersey1.18 Zip bundle downloaded from the same site) . Then followed  @SparkOn 's Answer.It worked!

Answer (score 3):

Because the url pattern specified is

```
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
```

Moreover your servlet tag should be like this

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>Package1</param-value>
      </init-param>
</servlet>
```

you can specify additional path in your resource-method to call it individually like

```
    @Path("/hello")
    public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Path("/intextform")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello from Jersey!";

       }
   }
```

Then  right-click on the project and run on server

Try this url

```
http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemoProject/rest/hello/intextform
```

Comment: did you do whatever i specified in the answer and add the mapping path as well

Comment: What do you mean by fully qualified package name?

Comment: the name of your package specified at the top of your servlet after running it on server access the path specified with the path annotation above the resource method

Comment: so in mycase it is fully qualified package name would be "Package1".Right?

Comment: How will we know you you did not post your class whichever it is you need to specify that one

Comment: do you have the required jars in the classpath

Comment: change to whatever i said in your code and then post the updated code and the stackstrace

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not with Jersey 2.1, problem is with your servlet class.
You should use the following servlet class in your web.xml ( for all Jersey 2.x applications )

```
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

instead of :

```
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
```

Then everything will work fine.

Finally, your servlet should be:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>Package1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First please replace `<servlet-class>Package1.Hello</servlet-class>` with `<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-cl‌​ass>` in your web.xml and rerun the application

Please try the below URL it should work:

```
http://localhost:8080/JerseyDemoProject/Package1/rest/hello
```

Provided that you have mapped your controller to `@PATH("/hello")`